# Why do we need the Zeroth Law of Thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have just recently started learning some very basic thermodynamics and there is one question that has been driving me crazy:

> Why do we even need the Zeroth law of thermodynamics?

The law states:

*If a body A, be in thermal equilibrium with two other bodies, B and C, then B and C are in thermal equilibrium with one another.* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_law_of_thermodynamics#Physical_meaning_of_the_usual_statement_of_the_zeroth_law))

This seems like the most obvious statement ever. How could *B* and *C* not be in thermal equilibrium?

While looking for an answer I came across a Khan Academy video that deals with this exact question. The lecturer in the video says:

"...yeah our universe is like that but think about it a little harder, you could problably think of a universe where it might not be like that." ([Video](https://youtu.be/j-enxYaQMdA?t=195))

This just confused me even more. If we follow that logic wouldn't we have to formulate something like Newtons Zeroth Law or Keplers Zeroth law too?

Comment: You need the zeroth law to define 'empirical' temperature.

Comment: Instead of calling it "obvious", call it "axiomatic."  If we don't have axioms, then our reasoning has nothing to stand on.

Comment: From a physical perspective you don't "need" it. I would agree with James that the zeroth law is so obvious as to be superficial. One does "need" it in a mathematical sense as an axiom for the formalism but to be honest, it has zero physical content. As for Quantum's remark... forget everything you have ever heard about "empirical temperature". It's as useful as the phlogiston.

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys. I think the "axiomatic explanation" somewhat does it for me. @CuriousOne if it has zero physical content, why is it mentioned in so many physics books?

Comment: @CuriousOne, it may be obvious to some, but only based on experience. That's why it does have physical content. Without experience, it is entirely possible to have a scheme where A is in equilibrium with B when the two are brought into contact, the same for A and C, but B and C are not in equilibrium when brought into contact so heat flows. The fact we never observed such strange behaviour is based on observation and is a law of physics.

Comment: @JánLalinský: I agree that it is based on observation, but it's still obvious. Unlike in mathematics we aren't spelling out every obvious thing. In Newtonian mechanics, for instance, we aren't saying "There is matter.", even though it is a necessary ingredient in the theory. I would put this on roughly the same level. If we believe Wikipedia, then the notion of the zeroth law wasn't even in existence until 1935: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_law_of_thermodynamics#History. I think that's a pretty clear sign that it wasn't really necessary in the minds of the important folks.

Comment: The zeroth law allows you to calibrate and use a thermometer.   If it reads 'x' when connected to A, and 'x' when connected to B, A and B are at the same temperature.   Without the zeroth law, you cannot test a prospective thermometer (or calibrate one).

Comment: Is there anything that does not follows its own zeroth law? Like I can say zeroth law of electric potential is if A do not exchange charge with B and B with C, then they are in electric equilibrium and A and  B won't exchange charge with eachother.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How could B and C not be in thermal equilibrium?

**A is in contact with B**: nothing happens

```
      B
   .
A
```

**A is in contact with C**: nothing happens

```
A
   .
      C
```

**B is in contact with C**: lots of heat is being transferred to B

```
          B

          ↑

          C
```

We have not observed bodies that would behave this way. That is the content of the zeroth law.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @bluemoon, you're welcome.

Comment: The same reasoning in your answer could be applied to pressure (if the systems are deformable) or even chemical potential (if the systems can exchange particles). Why do we not need 4th and 5th laws to introduce the equivalence classes arising from pressure and chemical potential if we need the 0'th law to introduce the equivalence classes arising from temperature?

Comment: The reasoning is specific to heat transfer of bodies that are in contact, with no mention of temperature. I don't see what you mean by applying it to pressure or chemical potential.